# display err:resource previously defined here

Tags: android, android-studio

When i run my project, display:

> error: resource previously defined here.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource previously defined here.

[image: Image of Error]

Comment: show your code..

Comment: try... invalidate caches/ restart option. and also check the xml file some duplicate attributes is there.

Comment: I try invalidate caches/ restart, but still display same screen.

Comment: add app:module dependencies Photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before:

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

After:

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

remove 
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'

It is OK.

cause:
    I created new activity, Android Studio add a line in build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

Comment: Remove ConstraintLayout